# Decoding h.264 with Android MediaCodec

Tags: android, h.264, codec, decoding, android-mediacodec

I'm having a great deal of trouble decoding h.264 with the Android `MediaCodec`.  I am receiving a raw h.264 stream from a drone via a custom API (provided). The API gives me a byte [] of values.

Pretty straightforward, I am initializing the `MediaCodec` decoder like this (I have the SPS and PPS declared elsewhere):

```
int width = 640;
int height = 480;
videoFormat = "video/avc";

format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat( videoFormat, width, height );
format.setString("KEY_MIME", videoFormat );

mCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType( videoFormat );

format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap( NAL_sps ));
format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap( NAL_pps ));

mCodec.configure( format, null, null, 0 );
```

For the time being, I am not rendering the `dequeuedOutputBuffer` to my `Surface` so I can inspect what is coming out.

The strange problem is, once I do get a valid output buffer from the decoder, the result is garbage.  For my 640 x 480 testing, the number of bytes I get from the decoder is correct (460800 bytes) which I assume is Semi Planar 4:2:0 (640x480x1.5).  However, the values are all garbage, i.e. `0x80 0x80 0x80` ... for the entire byte array.

Does anyone know if there are h.264 limitations to what the `MediaCodec` can decode?  I have noted that according to the `MediaFormat` API, "all keys not marked optional are mandatory".  I've tried to set all of the 'mandatory' fields for the `MediaFormat` and still detect no valid output.

I tried to decode the data directly to my `Surface` and noticed most of the window is grey and occasionally, I will get a few scan lines of what looks like valid video, and then back to grey.

Any idea what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: A couple of points needs clarification. Why `ByteBuffer.wrap` is employed for `SPS` and `PPS` content. Also, can you please share the `SPS` and `PPS` data to understand what is actually going into the `codec`. `MediaCodec` is an `API`, the actual implementation of which is handled by the underlying codec. In my view, there could be an issue that `SPS` and `PPS` may not have the start code due to which the underlying component may not have decoded this content successfully. Please share the dumps to help you further.

Comment: Are you sure the stream is valid? Capture a stream, play it back with a known-good player to confirm its validity, then use it for all testing rather than a live stream. The fact that the decoding appears to be working suggests that the codec is accepting and decoding the data, so it would be good to rule out GIGO.

Comment: I figured out my problem.  It had to do with my lack of understanding of the h.264 format.  My stream producer was firing off events as discrete NAL units, but not a complete Access Unit.  So I modified my code to search for the Access Unit Delimiter (0x09 in my case) and then buffered the rest of the NAL units I received on my event until I detected the next ACD instance and then send that entire Access Unit to the MediaCodec.  Works like a charm now, stupid user error!

Comment: @MatDePasquale could you share the code? I'm facing the same problem and it drives me instane...

Comment: @synthomat What part of your code isn't working?  Are you not getting MediaCodec output buffer events?  Are you sure you have a complete Access Unit?

Comment: @MatDePasquale no, I wasn't sure. We are doing a drone project (Phantom 2 Vision +) and we just found out, that the drone is sending single NALUs to the API. I think we almost solved the issue. But due to the lack of time I didn't mess around with it further. I will get back on this topic soon :)

Comment: @MatDePasquale when we saved the stream to a file, we could play it with the MediaCodec. But as we get a continuous byte-stream from the API and MediaExtractor can only read from either HTTP or File, this wasn't an option.

Comment: On your initial decoding, make sure you junk everything you receive until you get a packet with your sync word and start code of "0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x09" then build your packet from there.  Buffer everything after that until you get this same start code.  It sounds like you might be out of sync initially.  The single NALU screwed me up too initially.  The Phantom 2 just gives you just the slices.  Once you queue these up from 0x09 ... 0x09 you should have a complete Access Unit and MediaCodec can process it.